# Rails has_many through: association or simple has_many/belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

It's been a while since I've used a join table so I'm looking to refresh my memory on best practice usage.

I have a Rails 3.2.19 app that has a Unit model and I will be adding a Maintenance model.  The idea is to create a resource to add maintenance records for each unit.  So for instance when the tires are rotated or the oil is changed a maintenance record is created and the unit is assigned to that maintenance record.

I'd like to be able to iterate over each maintenance record in a view, displaying the unit name, type of maintenance, and details of what maintenance was performed.

I'm unsure of the best way to do this via associations.  Here was my initial thought:

**unit.rb**

```
has_many :maintenances
```

**maintenance.rb**

```
attr_accessible :unit_id
belongs_to :unit
```

That should allow me to iterate over each maintenance object and display the records for a particular unit. But something doesn't seem right.  I'm wondering if I need to setup a join table and do a has_many :through like this.

**unit.rb**

```
has_many :unit_maintenances
has_many :maintenances, through: :unit_maintenances
```

**maintenance.rb**

```
has_many :unit_maintenances
has_many :units, through: :unit_maintenances
```

**unit_maintenance.rb**

```
attr_accessible :maintenance_id, :unit_id
  belongs_to :maintenance
  belongs_to :unit
```

I am a bit unsure if I'm going overboard here and if I even need a join table considering there will be multiple maintenance records each with one unit assigned to it.  I'm thinking that a basic has_many and belongs_to association will work but I'm also wondering if I need to do a join table at all.

I'd also like to be able to see all maintenance records by truck, search by truck in the view, and also setup alerts if a certain threshold is met (like oil_change_mileage is > 5000).

If I can clarify what I'm trying to do here, please let me know.  But basically I'm setting up maintenance records for each unit so we can keep a record of what was done and hopefully build it up into something a bit more robust.

Comment: Will a single Maintenance (which isn't a great name, by the way, as evidenced by the fact that "maintenances" is not a word) ever have more than one Unit? From your description it seems like it won't, in which case a join table is definitely overkill.

Comment: I agree, the Model name Maintenance is probably a bad idea.  ServiceRecord or Service would probably be more appropriate.  And the answer to your question is no.  A maintenance record will only have one unit assigned to it.  I figured the join table was overkill, just thought I'd ask.